# Alternative to for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, dplyr

i have this script:

```
x<-seq(1,5)
y<-seq(6,10)
z<-sample(25)
x.range <- range(x)  
y.range <- range(y)
df <- expand.grid(x = seq(from = x.range[1], to = x.range[2], by = 1), y = seq(from = y.range[1], 
                                                                                 to = y.range[2], by = 1))
df$z<-z

x1<-c(1,2,3)
y1<-c(6,7,8)
z1<-c(10,12,13)
df_1<-data.frame(x1,y1,z1)
n<-length(df_1$x1)
df_pred<-data.frame(0,0,0)
names(df_pred)[1:3] <- c("x", "y", "z_pred")

for(i in 1:n)
{df_pred[i,]<-filter(df, x==df_1$x1[i], y==df_1$y1[i])}
sqm <- mean((df_pred[,3]-df_1[,3])^2)
```

I want to calculate the quadratic error between z value of df and z1 value of df_1. To do this i use a loop for to extract the rows that i need from df, basing on x1 and y1 values of df_1.
I ask you if there is something different to this for loop, to do the same thing (using, for example, dplyr package). Thanks.

Comment: On a side note `names(df_pred)[1:3] <- c("x", "y", "z_pred")` only needs to be `names(df_pred) <- c("x", "y", "z_pred")`.

Comment: What is your `for` loop supposed to accomplish? When I run it, I get and error.

Comment: On a second side note, it appears that you already know the size of your df_pred data.frame. In this situation, it is much better to pre-allocate it: `df_pred<-data.frame("x"=rep(0,n), "y"= rep(0,n), "z_pred"=rep(0, n))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you name columns of df_1 as "x","y"and "z" similar to df then you can use

```
df_1 <- data.frame(x=x_1,y=y_1,z=z_1)
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df,df_1,by=c("x","y"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your loop for yet you want to try this. I use it to replace your loop.

```
df_pred <- subset(df, x %in% df_1$x1 & y %in% df_1$y1)
```

Let me know if it solves your problem